# Unable to get LabJack U3 model loaded into PyCharm properly

Tags: python

I am trying to use a LabJack product U3 using Python and I am using PyCharm for development of my code. I am new to both Python and PyCharm FYI.  In the LabJack documentation they say to run python setup.py install in the directory I down loaded there Python links for using there device. I did this and when run under straight Python console can get the import u3 to run and am able to access the U3 device.  Yet when I run this in PyCharm I can not get it to run.  It always tells me module not found.  I have asked LabJack for help but they do not know PyCharm.  I have looked on the net but I can seem to see how to get the module properly under PyCharm.  Could i please get some help on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

First Yll download that module inside of pycharm settings if it's still not working then import module in terminal of pycharm then try to run you're python script